# iPhone app rejected because of metadata issues

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

My iPhone app has been rejected because of Metadata issues.Apple states that i need to make changes to the support urls.They are saying that i need to make corresponding changes in metadata in iTunes connect and resubmit.

I gave my email address for Support Email Address
As i don't have a website i gave apples home page(www.apple.com) as the support url.(I think this is where i botched up!What do i enter here?)
I left the other two url fields empty.

How should i proceed now?

Has anyone encountered this problem before??
Any solutions  and comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a facebook page is OK.
Apple validated my app with a facebook page as support page

Answer (score 4):

You need a website for support. Grab some cheap hosting, set up a domain with a few static support pages (linking to your support email, preferably), change the metadata, and resubmit.

Comment: Will a facebook page or a blogger page count as a page??

Answer (score 1):

I have actually seen some apps just listed with a blank website, so looks like Apple is OK with that. e.g your website could be listed as:

> http://

But - it's not actually all that hard to create a simple website. If you're developing iOS apps, it's not a bad thing to know how to do :)

If you want to give it a go, then check out Wordpress. I use it to run my [iOS developer website](http://icemediacreative.com/) - it took maybe a day to set up, find some cheap hosting, etc. That may seem like a lot of time, but it's a learning experience, and definitely worth doing IMO :)

Comment: Thanx for usr suggestion!! m planning to use google sites.. lets c how soon i get the website up and running:)